# How can i use progress bar in non length specific tasks or parallel loop?

Tags: c#, progress-bar, task

I need progress bar in windows form application but my process is not length specific so I can't maximum value to progressbar.

I must increment progress bar value using LongProcess class Run method elapsed time.

```
void start_click()
{
    button1.Enabled=false;

    Task.Factory.StartNew(()=>{
        Parallel.Foreach(files,f=>{
            LongProcess process =new LongProcess(); // Long-running process (is not my control)
            process.Run(f); 
                    //progressBarValueIncrement();

        });
    }).ContinueWith(t=>{
        // completed
        BeginInvoke(new Action(() =>    button1.Enabled=true));
    });
}
```

How can i implement this?

Comment: You can use cyclic progress bars, which shows just something is in progress, Also you can approximate your app running time, and stop in last step, then stop it when progress done completely.

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something here but if you know the number of files you're iterating over with the foreach, isn't this a trivial increment by 1/Count each time one finishes?

Comment: @MarkSmith I should increment progress value while running LongProcess not after the process

Comment: If you have a large number of files, why not just update the bar each time a file finishes? I would argue that any more than 25 files would be more than enough granularity for a progress bar. Is it really that important to update every 1% instead of every 4% in that case? Unless all 25 ran simultaneously, but that's unlikely.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you could increment the progress bar with some percentage of the remaining unfilled value.  This would mean that the progress bar never filled up though and would get fuller more and more slowly.

So in the first increment you fill the progress bar 50%, then next increment you fill 50% of the remainder, so 25% for a total of 75%, then 50% of remaining 25%, total 87.5% etc etc.

you may want to stage it so that the %age you used was based on how full the progress bar was, so start with 5% at the beginning so it doesn't fill up too quickly at the start, then move to higher percentages so you can see the bar moving still near the end...

If you don't know how long something is going to take though, is a progress bar appropriate?  Maybe you would be better with something that showed progress was happening, but not how much has been completed...

Comment: I'd also question the appropriateness of the progress-bar UI pattern in this case.